# List of the valid operators for each datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder if someone knows where can I find a list of all the datatypes of MySQL and for each datatype all it's valid operators.

Thank you.

Comment: Refer the mysql documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html and for your kind attention Stackoverflow is a place you can ask programmatic questions and not just references!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on [mysql doc.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html)

Answer (score 4):

In documentation, where else?

Chapter 10. [Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-types.html)

Chapter 11.1. [Function and Operator Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/func-op-summary-ref.html)

Answer (score 1):

i believe, you can find the answers on all your questions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html)